# Calculate Same date values from dimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, date

I have Following Array

```
$my_array = Array ( [0] => Array ( [date] => 2014-03-25 [total] => 649 ) [1] => Array ( [date] => 2014-03-29 [total] => 415.36 ) [2] => Array ( [date] => 2014-03-29 [total] => 29181.75 ) [3] => Array ( [date] => 2014-03-29 [total] => 1577.88 ) [4] => Array ( [date] => 2014-03-31 [total] => 849.4 ) [5] => Array ( [date] => 2014-04-11 [total] => 21382.2 ) [6] => Array ( [date] => 2014-04-16 [total] => 45022.5 ) )
```

$my_array in foreach output inner arrays like this.

```
Array ( [date] => 2014-03-25 [total] => 649 )
Array ( [date] => 2014-03-29 [total] => 415.36 )
Array ( [date] => 2014-03-29 [total] => 29181.75 )
Array ( [date] => 2014-03-29 [total] => 1577.88 )
Array ( [date] => 2014-03-31 [total] => 849.4 )
Array ( [date] => 2014-04-11 [total] => 21382.2 )
Array ( [date] => 2014-04-16 [total] => 45022.5 )
```

There are 3 sales for date 29 , I am trying to get Total sales of each day which should output.

Date 1 total sales
date2 total sales
date 3 total sales (if 3 sales their total)

can anyone help me please?

Comment: This may help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18853327/get-averages-of-values-from-multidimensional-array-where-date-keys-match

Comment: Is this a result set from a database? If so, you should query for the totals as your result set instead. Otherwise,  Shankar's explanation of array_walk () is spot on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this using `array_walk` and by implementing this call-back function.

```
<?php
$my_array = Array ( '0' => Array ( 'date' => '2014-03-25' ,'total' => 649 ), '1' => Array ( 'date' => '2014-03-29' ,'total' => 415.36 ), '2' => Array ( 'date' => '2014-03-29' ,'total' => 29181.75 ), '3' => Array ( 'date' => '2014-03-29', 'total' => 1577.88 ) ,'4' => Array ( 'date' => '2014-03-31', 'total' => 849.4 ), '5' => Array ( 'date' => '2014-04-11', 'total' => 21382.2 ) ,'6' => Array ( 'date' => '2014-04-16', 'total' => 45022.5 ) );
$new_arr = array();
array_walk($my_array,function ($v,$k) use(&$new_arr)
{
    array_key_exists($v['date'],$new_arr) ? $new_arr[$v['date']] = $new_arr[$v['date']]+$v['total'] : $new_arr[$v['date']]=$v['total'];
});
echo "<pre>";
print_r($new_arr);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [2014-03-25] => 649
    [2014-03-29] => 31174.99
    [2014-03-31] => 849.4
    [2014-04-11] => 21382.2
    [2014-04-16] => 45022.5
)
```

As you can see , the total sales are the values and the dates are the keys. The total sales have been added up and is shown next to each dates.

Comment: Thank you very much shankar :) I have implemented your helping code here. in my this system http://codecanyon.net/item/php-point-of-sale/7511262 let me know if i can help you in anything. You solved my problem have good day bro.